# Building JSON of ORM and Relationships with Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, orm, eloquent

Actually, i do this to build json of many ORM objects in controller :

```
Response::json(Project::all());
```

Result :

```
[
    {id: 1, name: 'test1'},
    {id: 2, name: 'test2'},
    {id: 3, name: 'test3'}
]
```

Now i want :

```
[
    {
        id: 1, 
        name: 'test1',
        levels: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'level1'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'level2'
            }
        ]
    },
    {id: 2, name: 'test2', levels: []},
    {id: 3, name: 'test3', levels: []}
]
```

My Project model is like this :

```
class Project extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'projects';

    public function levels()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Level', 'project_has_levels');
    }

}
```

How do you do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading).

```
Response::json(Project::with('levels')->get());
```